# Have some strange error when using jquery-ajaxfileupload in jquery-jeditable.js

Tags: ajax, file-upload, jeditable

When you push upload button, or cancel I got that error. But other editable fields without upload are working fine. 
Using:
Jeditable - jQuery in place edit plugin Version 1.7.1

Don't know what to do with that. 
Thank's for your answers.
   [image: Error]

```
$.editable.addInputType('ajaxupload', {
/* create input element */
element: function (settings) {
    settings.onblur = 'ignore';
    var input = $('<input type="file" id="upload" name="upload"/>');
    $(this).append(input);
    return (input);
},
content: function (string, settings, original) { /* do nothing */ },
plugin: function (settings, original) {
    var form = this;
    form.attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
    $("button:submit", form).bind('click', function () {
       $.ajaxFileUpload({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/EZhandler.ashx?exId=" + GetExhibitorId() + "&exhibitionId=" + GetExhibitionId()+"&type=logo",
            secureuri: false,
            fileElementId: 'upload',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data, status) {
                $(original).html(data);
                original.editing = false;
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function (data, status, e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        });
        return (false);
    });
}
```

});

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.logo').editable(function (value, settings) {
        return value;
    },
    {
        type: 'ajaxupload',
        submit: 'Upload',
        cancel: 'Cancel',
        style: 'inherit',
        tooltip: "Click to upload..."
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(original).html(data);  - check data status, mb it's null